# Update nested value in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write a routine that updates values in an XML file and believe I'm close. Here's an example of the XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is generated by the GPS_Client program. -->
<Sites>
  <Site>
    <Id>A</Id>
    <add key="landingName" value="Somewhere" />
    <add key="landingLat" value="47.423719" />
    <add key="landingLon" value="-123.011364" />
    <add key="landingAlt" value="36" />
  </Site>
  <Site>
    <Id>B</Id>
    <add key="landingName" value="Somewhere Else" />
    <add key="landingLat" value="45.629160" />
    <add key="landingLon" value="-128.882934" />
    <add key="landingAlt" value="327" />
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

The key is that I need to update a specific key without updating the rest of the keys with the same name.  Here's the current code:

```
        private void UpdateOrCreateAppSetting(string filename, string site, string key, string value)
{
    string path = "\"@" + filename + "\""; 
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path); 
    var list = from appNode in doc.Descendants("appSettings").Elements()
            where appNode.Attribute("key").Value == key
            select appNode;
    var e = list.FirstOrDefault();

    // If the element doesn't exist, create it
    if (e == null) {
        new XElement(site,
            new XAttribute(key, value));
    // If the element exists, just change its value
    } else {
        e.Element(key).Value = value; 
        e.Attribute("value").SetValue(value);
    }
}
```

I assume I need to concatenate site, Id and key in some way, but don't see how it's done.

Comment: It should update in-place.  What behavior are you seeing?  Note that currently you are not writing the XML anywhere or returning it so the only way to check is with the debugger.

Comment: The code doesn't match your XML. `Descendants("appSettings")`  there's no nodes of `appSettings` in the demo XML you show.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this XmlLib](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/), you can have it create the node if it doesn't exist automatically.

```
private void UpdateOrCreateAppSetting(string filename, string site, 
                                      string key, string value)
{
    string path = "\"@" + filename + "\""; 
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    XPathString xpath = new XPathString("//Site[Id={0}]/add[@key={1}]", site, key);
    XElement node = doc.Root.XPathElement(xpath, true); // true = create if not found
    node.Set("value", value, true); // set as attribute, creates attribute if not found
    doc.Save(filename);
}
```